# How to overlap bars using ggplot2? just like 'add=TRUE' in barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlap

As we can see in this graph ([full graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFngs.png)):

[image]

There are two variables, the lighter orange bar shows the total value and another one is showing the partial variable. How can I organize those two bars together? (not 'stack', because I want both bars to start from the bottom)

```
ggplot(bad_drivers2, aes(State, nums)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill= "royalblue") + 
coord_flip()
ggplot(bad_drivers2, aes(State, not_distracted_num)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill= "blue") + 
coord_flip()
```

Comment: Try adding a second `geom_bar` layer to the same plot but with a different `y` aesthetic.  Like `+ geom_col( aes(y = not_distracted), fill = "blue")`

Comment: @aosmith Thank you, it works, but the color "blue' never show up, it's showing red color all the time, and the legend is also weird.(how can I show the plot to you in comments?)

Comment: upload the image somewhere and edit the question to reflect what you have now tried. ideally with some sample data to illustrate

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/search?q=type:image, hope this works

Comment: At the moment you are not adding a legend in your code (as long as `fill` is outside of `aes()`.  It will help people help you if you add a reproducible example.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some tips on how to do that.

Comment: It was my fault, I put fill in aes(), now it has been solved. Thank you and have a good day